# Is it possible to extract review's keywords using Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I would like to extract data of "Users often mention" from Google Reviews, in order to get those reviews and value (count).

Is this possible using some Google API?

[image]

Comment: It looks like this is from the Google Maps App, not from the APIs. Can you confirm? If so, please note that Google Maps App and the Google Maps API are different platforms, so you should set your expectation that they have different features and functionalities.